# Including a Python Script in a .net solution

Tags: python, .net, numpy, sklearn-pandas

I have a Python 2.7 Script that does the following things:

1. Read data from a database and manipulate them with numpy and pandas
2. Perform a clustering with sklearn
3. Write these data on a database

I want to include this script in .net solution, and I have no idea on where to start.

Some possibilities:

1. Call the script from a .net module in the solution. In don't like this because we will need to deploy the solution on customers' servers, so they should not be able to see the script
2. Create an executable file that takes some input (the db address, for instance) and is "inside" in some way (no idea how) the solution.

Any advice?